# php get id from string using number of characters

Tags: php

I have string like this

```
https://example.com/offers/show?ID=d5589152-1ba7-4bab-b810-1d43e734575e&something=blabla&somethingelse=blabla2
```

sometimes string looks different

```
https://example.com/o/ABC/PP-Bin/4be93fd6-1380-4403-9945-0c5bc54d05e6?sName=Bam+2rnt
```

I want to extract ID from this string by number of characters.
Every ID has 8-4-4-4-12 characters

Comment: You can use `preg_match()` to get the id: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sWs

Comment: that ID is a `GUID` or `unique Identifier`. read question suggested by showdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
$subject = "https://example.com/offers/show?ID=d5589152-1ba7-4bab-b810-1d43e734575e&something=blabla&somethingelse=blabla2";

preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}/", $subject, $matches);

print_R($matches);
```